# I cant install ubuntu because of parrotSec

Tags: system-installation

A couple of months ago I tried to install parrotSec on my laptop. I set the password to the hard drive and the installation crashed. Me being me I unplugged the flash drive with parrotSec and shut the laptop. Today I tried to install ubuntu and its says:
"Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #2 SCSI1 (0, 0, 0) (sda)..."
there is a progress bar and it hasnt moved in that last 40 minutes. My laptop is connected to the internet and my internet is really good.My question is, is it because I set the password to the hard drive a long time ago or am I just really impatient?

Note: I suck with linux

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! If both distros are crashing during installation, there also might be a hardware problem… How old is your laptop? What’s the drive type and capacity?

Comment: My laptop is a lenovo yoga 2. the install screen still says: "Creating ext4 file system for / in partition #2 SCSI1 (0, 0, 0) (sda)..." and the progress bar has not moved. It has been about 14 hours. the yoga 2 has a 500gb and hard drive

Comment: I guess I should add: What I really think is happening here is that parrotSec encrypted my hard drive. I believe that I need to know the password for it (Which I dont) ParrotSec never finished downloading. When trying to install ubuntu the progress did not move - I waited aprox. 36 hours and it didnt move so I turned of the computer.

Comment: An OS can encrypt _data_ in a partition on the hard drive. During OS installation, the whole partition should be replaced with new contents. Have you selected _Erase disk and install Ubuntu_? If still not successful, you should run [Boot-Info](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and provide the URL with detailed info of your hard disk.